# Compilation error only when using the repl

Tags: raku, read-eval-print-loop, rakudo

I am getting an error only when the code is entered line by line in the repl. It works when the whole program is pasted at once, or from the command line.

```
class A {
    method a () {
    return 1;
    }
}

class B {
    method b () {
    return 2;
    }
}
```

This is the error statement:

```
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling:
Package 'B' already has a method 'b' (did you mean to declare a multi method?)
```

This screen shot might make it clearer. On the left I just pasted the code, and on the right I entered it line by line. The code is still working but what is causing the error?

[image: pasting vs line-by-line]

For some reason, I could not reproduce this using just one class.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I get an error also in the first form, at least in the latest version.

Comment: @jjmerelo: Yes, I just tried the latest version and it is reporting the error even when pasted. My installed version was built a month ago and it reports the error only when typed line by line. So this is a bug?

Comment: It seems strange, I cannot reproduce this using only one class.

Comment: as indicated below, it might not so much be a bug as simply something the REPL is not prepared (or should be prepared) for. You might want to file it as a bug, but in this case my advice would be to use an IDE.

Comment: btw, it does not complain, if you close these with `}}` one-liner

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [Comma](https://commaide.com/) is the bees knees. And I almost never use the repl. But I enjoy:

- **Golfing** Your example is a more than adequate [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). But I love minimizing bug examples.
- **Speculating** I think I can see what's going on.
- **Searching issue queues** Rakudo has *two* issue queues on GH: [old](https://github.com/raku/old-issues-tracker/issues/) and [new](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/).
- **Spelunking compiler code** Rakudo is mostly written in Raku; maybe we can work out what this problem is in the REPL code (which is part of the compiler)?

## Golfing

First, the bug:

```
Welcome to ™ v2021.03.
Implementing the ™ programming language v6.d.
Built on MoarVM version 2021.03.

To exit type 'exit' or '^D'
> # 42
Nil
> { subset a
* 
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling:
Redeclaration of symbol 'a'.
at line 3
------> <BOL>⏏<EOL>
```

Commentary:

1. To get on the fairway, enter any line that's not just whitespace, and press Enter.
2. Pick the right iron; open a block with `{`, declare some named type, and press Enter. The REPL indicates you're on the green by displaying the `*` multi-line prompt.
3. To sink the ball, just hit Enter.

---

Second, golfing in aid of speculation:

```
> # 42
Nil
> { BEGIN say 99
99
* }
99
>
```

(`BEGIN` marks code that is to be run during compilation as soon as the compiler encounters it.)

## Speculating

Why does the initial `# 42` evaluation matter? Presumably the REPL tries to maintain declarations / state (of variables and types etc) during a REPL session.

And as part of that it's presumably remembering all previous code in a session.

And presumably it's seeing anything but blank lines as counting as previous code.

And the mere existence of some/any previous code somehow influences what state the REPL is maintaining and/or what it's asking the compiler to do.

Maybe.

---

Why does a type declaration matter when, say, a variable declaration doesn't?

Presumably the REPL and/or compiler is distinguishing between these two kinds of declaration.

Ignoring the REPL, when compiling code, a repeated `my` declaration only raises a *warning*, whereas a repeated type declaration is an error. Quite plausibly that's why?

---

Why does a type declaration have this effect?

Presumably the type successfully compiles and only after that an exception is thrown (because the code is incomplete due to the missing closing brace).

Then the REPL asks the compiler to *again* try to compile the multi-line code thus far entered, with whatever additional code the user has typed (in my golf version I type nothing and just hit Enter, adding no more code).

This repeated compile attempt includes the type declaration again, which type declaration, because the compilation state from the prior attempt to compile the multi-line code is somehow being retained, is seen by the compiler as a *repeat* declaration, causing it to throw an exception that causes the REPL to exit multi-line mode and report the error.

---

In other words, the REPL loop is presumably something like:

1. As each line is entered, pass it to the compiler, which compiles the code and throws an exception if anything goes wrong.
2. If an exception is thrown:

   2.1 If in multi-line mode (with `*` prompt), then exit multi-line mode (go back to `>` prompt) and display exception message.

   2.2 Else (so not in multi-line mode), if analysis (plausibly very basic) of the exception and/or entered code suggests multi-line mode would be useful, then enter that mode (with `*` prompt). In multi-line mode, the entire multi-line of code so far is recompiled each time the user presses Enter.

   2.3 Else, display exception message.
3. (Obviously there's something else going on related to initialization given the need to start with some evaluation to manifest this bug, but that may well be a completely distinct issue.)

## Searching

I've browsed through all open Rakudo issues in its old and new queues on GH that match 'repl'. I've selected four that illustrate the range of difficulties the REPL has with maintaining the state of a session:

- [REPL loses custom operators](https://github.com/Raku/old-issue-tracker/issues/6446#issuecomment-570884299). "Interestingly, if a postfix operator like this is exported by a module which is loaded by the REPL, the REPL can successfully parse that operator just once, after which it will fail with an error similar to the above." Is this related to the way the bug this SO is focused on doesn't manifest until it's a *second* or later evaluation?
- [Perl6 REPL forgets the definition of infix sub](https://github.com/Raku/old-issue-tracker/issues/6333). Looks like a dupe of the above issue, but includes extra debugging goodies from Brian Duggan. ❤️
- [REPL messes up namespaces when Foo is used after Foo::Bar](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/1690).
- [In REPL cannot bind to scalars declared on earlier lines](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/1565#issue-300007592).

One thing I haven't done is checked whether these bugs all still exist. My guess is they do. And there are many others like them. Perhaps they have a somewhat common cause? I've no idea. Perhaps we need to look at the code...

## Spelunking

A search of the Rakudo sources for 'repl' quickly led to a [`REPL`](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/master/src/core.c/REPL.pm6) module. Less than 500 lines of high level Raku code! \o/ (For now, let's just pretend we can pretty much ignore digging into the code it calls...)

From my initial browser, I'll draw attention to:

- A [`sub repl`](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/47ebc86c98351f5fdb7349642281158bfb79711a/src/core.c/REPL.pm6#L459-L463):

  ```
  sub repl(*%_) {
    my $repl := REPL.new(nqp::getcomp("Raku"), %_, True);
    nqp::bindattr($repl,REPL,'$!save_ctx',nqp::ctxcaller(nqp::ctx));
    $repl.repl-loop(:no-exit);
  }
  ```

  [Blame](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blame/master/src/core.c/REPL.pm6) shows that [Liz added this a couple months ago](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/commit/4183cdaf37c842fb74eb5a08c2cf12075d4c55ec). It's very tangential to this bug, but I'm guessing methods and variables with `ctx` in their name are pretty central to things so this is hopefully a nice way to start pondering that.
- [`method repl-eval`](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/cf7b4f18da9ebf71185ff0fa5412612e80d6baa0/src/core.c/REPL.pm6#L278-L310). 30 lines or so.
- [`REPL: loop { ... }`](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/cf7b4f18da9ebf71185ff0fa5412612e80d6baa0/src/core.c/REPL.pm6#L336-L397). 60 lines or so.

That'll do for tonight. I'll post this then return to it all another day.

Comment: "To get on the fairway, enter any line that's not just whitespace, and press Enter." By coincidence, just this week there's a thread on backslash-only lines in the Raku REPL (a.k.a. when you think you're entering a continuation character but you aren't):  https://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl6.users/2021/07/msg10039.html

Comment: @jubilatious1 ❶ Your comment led me to try entering a backslash. It gave the `{}` response as your thread discussed. But it also did *not* get me on the fairway. Same with any code the compiler rejects. After a few more seconds experimenting my guess is the backslash is leading to a warning ("You can't backslash that") that's being eaten. So: ❷ Make step 1 something like "enter any line that compiles without an exception -- error or warning". ❸ At less than 500 lines of sparse and mostly uncomplicated looking Raku code, it seems worth studying REPL.pm, so that's what I hope to get to.

Answer (score 6):

I can reproduce that error, and looks like a REPL bug, or simply something the REPL is not prepared to do. This, for instance, will also raise an exception:

```
class A {
    method a() {
    return 1;
    }
};

class foo {
    has $.bar = 3;
};
```

In either form, either pasting it directly or in pieces. It's always the second class. It's probably related to the way `EVAL` works, but I really don't know. At the end of the day, the REPL can only take you so far and I'm not totally sure this is within the use case. You might want to use [Comma](https://commaide.com/download) or any other IDE, like emacs, for anything that's more complicated than a line; Comma also provides help for evaluating expressions, and even grammars.

Comment: I came across this through `emacs`. Current  `raku-mode` for emacs does not seem to have much support for repl. It sends the whole buffer line by line to the repl, when I try to load a file. I hacked together something with `require` for files but things like `eval-region` etc.. will require the repl to have this capacity.