# Cannot use example about roles from official doc in Raku

Tags: raku, rakudo

Following this defenitions from [docs.raku](https://docs.raku.org/language/glossary#Abstract_class), I get the following error with rakudo 2022.03

```
platform-pro (pro) in ~ via ⬢ v12.4.0
❯ raku                                                                                                           ~
Welcome to Rakudo™ v2022.03.
Implementing the Raku® Programming Language v6.d.
Built on MoarVM version 2022.03.

To exit type 'exit' or '^D'
>  role Canine {
*  method bark { ... }
*  }
(Canine)
>  class Dog does Canine {
*  method bark { say  "Woof" }
*  }
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling:
Package 'Dog' already has a method 'bark' (did you mean to declare a multi method?)
at line 2
```

I changed the method to multi but:

```
>  role Canine {
*  method bark { ... }
*  }
(Canine)
>  class Dog does Canine {
*  multi method bark { say  "Woof" }
*  }
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling:
No appropriate parametric role variant available for 'Canine':
    Ambiguous call to '(Dog)'; these signatures all match:
      (::$?CLASS ::::?CLASS Mu $)
      (::$?CLASS ::::?CLASS Mu $)
```

Thanks to the comments it seems a problem in the REPL:

```
role Canine {
    method bark { say  "Woof" };
}

class Dog does Canine {
    method bark { say  "Woof" };
}

my $d = Dog.new();

$d.bark
```

if save this to a file and execute

```
☸ platform-pro (pro) in learn/raku/stackoverflow via  v3.9.10 (python-3.9.10) via  v6.d v2022.03
❯ raku prueba-roles.raku                                                                ~/learn/raku/stackoverflow
Woof
```

Comment: Does this also occur if you put this code in a script and run that?

Comment: I think this is more or less a dupe of an SO for which I wrote [a long and rambling answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68433840/1077672). If I'm right, I plan to write up a fresh answer here that's short and to the point of your particular example. But not tonight. Maybe I'll get lucky and someone else will read my answer and  progress things and/or write an answer here so I don't feel I have to.

Comment: For the convenience of later readers / possible answerers, a search of SO for [`[raku] code:"already has a method"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Braku%5D+code%3A%22already+has+a+method%22).

Comment: It's bad movie night for me, so I won't be answering tonight. But I've done some preliminary investigation. 1. Your SO is indeed a dupe of the earlier SO I linked. 2. I'm not going to mark this as a dupe but instead use it as an opportunity to write much the same answer in a completely different form. 3. Having read my earlier answer I find it's immediately obvious to me what's going on even before I even look at the code. 4. I hope to make headway when I look at the code again; I recall giving up last time, but I think/hope I did so too easily. 5. I think our goal ought be we file an issue.